# How To install gcc 5.2 on centos 7.1?

Tags: centos, centos7, gcc, g++

How To install gcc 5.2 on centos 7.1 ?
with g++,cpp ?

I compiled it once, but it need newer glibc which cannot be switched in system

Comment: [This isn't your actual problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912) What is your real problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can create repo from fedora and install gcc 5.1.1, it will be better than compile it.

```
cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/Fedora-Core23.repo
[warning:fedora]
name=fedora
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-23&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
EOF
```

then install  gcc

```
yum install gcc --enablerepo=warning:fedora
```

output:

```
========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Package                                           Arch                                      Version                                            Repository                                         Size
========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
gcc                                               x86_64                                    5.1.1-4.fc23                                       warning:fedora                                     19 M
Installing for dependencies:
cpp                                               x86_64                                    5.1.1-4.fc23                                       warning:fedora                                    8.5 M
glibc-devel                                       x86_64                                    2.22-2.fc23                                        warning:fedora                                    909 k
glibc-headers                                     x86_64                                    2.22-2.fc23                                        warning:fedora                                    497 k
isl                                               x86_64                                    0.14-4.fc23                                        warning:fedora                                    490 k
kernel-headers                                    x86_64                                    4.2.0-1.fc23                                       warning:fedora                                    992 k
libmpc                                            x86_64                                    1.0.2-4.fc23                                       warning:fedora                                     55 k
mpfr                                              x86_64                                    3.1.3-1.fc23                                       warning:fedora                                    213 k

Updating for dependencies:
binutils                                          x86_64                                    2.25-13.fc23                                       warning:fedora                                    5.6 M
glibc                                             x86_64                                    2.22-2.fc23                                        warning:fedora                                    3.6 M
glibc-common                                      x86_64                                    2.22-2.fc23                                        warning:fedora                                     11 M
libgcc                                            x86_64                                    5.1.1-4.fc23                                       warning:fedora                                     82 k
libgomp                                           x86_64                                    5.1.1-4.fc23                                       warning:fedora                                    146 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package  (+7 Dependent packages)
Upgrade             ( 5 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 52 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
```

Why do you preferred on gcc 5.2?

```
# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR  PURPOSE.
```

Comment: yeah, thx a lot. got this answer by myself too

Comment: I'm glad I could help you too

Comment: and why gcc 5.2 cause from 4.9 to 5.2 got about 30-40% optimisation

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html

Comment: adding Fedora repo to Centos7 (server with gui) horribly broke my installation.

Answer (score 6):

nano /etc/yum.repos.d/FedoraRepo.repo

```
[warning:fedora]
name=fedora
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-23&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://getfedora.org/static/34EC9CBA.txt
```

yum update gcc g++